# Latex error missing { inserted. \end{align}?

Tags: alignment, latex

I get this error when trying to compile the following code. It says "error missing { inserted. \end{align}".

```
\begin{align}
$$
d_r \quad &= \quad k_r, \\
d_{r-1} \quad &= \quad k_r + k_{r-1}, \\
d_{r-2} \quad &= \quad k_r + k_{r-1} + k_{r-2}.
$$
\end{align}
```

The output result I get is the one I want, I mean everything's aligned and nice but I keep getting the error. What is the problem here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing those two $$ and see if it works

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work though.

Comment: ok, in this case please post a [**MWE**](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so we can find where your problem is :)

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Remove the `$$`...`$$` as suggested [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/ENyXZUTd) and don't use the additional `\quad` spaces ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xShX.png)).